# Method overloading with dynamic casting

Tags: java, overloading

I'm looking into the method overloading of Java.
Take the next sample :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object object = "some String";
    System.out.println(object.getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println(belongsToAllowedTypes(object.getClass().cast(object)));
    String string = "another String";
    System.out.println(belongsToAllowedTypes(string));
}

public static boolean belongsToAllowedTypes(Object value) {
    return false;
}

public static boolean belongsToAllowedTypes(String value) {
    return true;
}
```

I'm expecting an output like :

```
String
True
True
```

Just because I get the String class and cast the Object to that class before I invoke the method.
But no luck, I'm getting `false` in the second `println`.
So it's still processed as an `Object` (however the class is `String`)

If I change it to :

```
System.out.println(belongsToAllowedTypes(String.class.cast(object)));
```

I do get a `True`.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: When you use getClass, it is returning a Class<? extends Object> and not a Class<String>.

Comment: @matt at runtime I do get Class<String> otherwise the simpleName isn't String.  But it's the issue of compile vs runtime.  Pitty because this could be sometime nice to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method to call is determined at compile time. So with `object` having type `Object` the type of

```
object.getClass().cast(object))
```

at compile time is an `Object` independent of the dynamic content of `object`.